# How to bundle dependencies in for Cython pyd file?

Tags: python, windows, cython

I'm trying to compile a Cython module, that uses certain external libraries(jsoncpp, libass), but after generating the pyd file, and trying to import it, it throws `ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cymodule: The specified module could not be found`. After searching a little, seems like that error might point to missing dependencies, so I downloaded Dependency Walker to check it, and it showed me this:

[image: Dependecy Walker]

Which seems to show that there are a lot of dll that the module depends on, but I don't understand what did I do wrong, or how to fix those dependencies. How can I add those files to my pyd?

For the compiler I'm using MSVC with Visual Studio 2022, and to install jsoncpp and libass I used vcpkg: `.\vcpkg\vcpkg install jsoncpp libass` (I cloned vcpkg from the Github repo and ran the bat file to install it). For the python I created a venv where I installed the required libraries(Cython, dotenv, etc).

This is the setup.py file I'm using:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension, find_packages
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from setuptools.command.install import install
import os
import shutil

libass_lib = ["C:","Users","user","Documents","Dev","vcpkg","installed","x64-windows","lib"]
libass_head = ["C:","Users","user","Documents","Dev","vcpkg","installed","x64-windows","include"]
libass_dll = ["C:","Users","user","Documents","Dev","vcpkg","installed","x64-windows","bin","ass.dll"]

json_lib = ["C:","Users","user","Documents","Dev","vcpkg","installed","x64-windows","lib"]
json_head = ["C:","Users","user","Documents","Dev","vcpkg","installed","x64-windows","include"]
json_dll = ["C:","Users","user","Documents","Dev","vcpkg","installed","x64-windows", "bin","jsoncpp.dll"]

libass_lib = os.sep.join(libass_lib)
libass_head = os.sep.join(libass_head)
libass_dll = os.sep.join(libass_dll)
json_lib = os.sep.join(json_lib)
json_head = os.sep.join(json_head)
json_dll = os.sep.join(json_dll)

ext_module = Extension(
    "cymodule",
    sources=["cymodule.pyx", "main.cpp"],
    language="c++",
    extra_compile_args=["-std=c++11"],
    libraries=["ass", "jsoncpp"],
    library_dirs=[libass_lib, json_lib],
    include_dirs=[libass_head, json_head],
)

setup(
    name="cymodule",
    packages=find_packages(),
    ext_modules=cythonize([ext_module], build_dir="."+os.sep+"cyfiles"),
    include_package_data=True,
)
```

I compile it with `python setup.py build_ext` which generates cymodule.cp310-win_amd64.pyd inside the cyfiles folder, but when I try to import it whit `from cyfiles.cymodule import main` then it throws that error. I honestly am not being able to understand about the dependencies, What do I need to modify for the compiled object to be able to be used? A similar setup to this works perfectly in Linux, but I'm not sure what to do to make it on Windows. I read in other topics to add the dependencies to the path, but I don't think I should add all those things showed in the Dependency Walker, and, for example, the Python one shows me too broken dependencies, but I've `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\` and `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\` there, so I'm not sure this might be the problem.